# MYSQL result from C# returns only one row even though the exact same query in workbench returns 4?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2019

Here's my C# to fetch the data from three tables respectively called Post, Like, Comments:

```
        MySqlConnection cn = null;

        MySqlCommand cm = Connect(ref cn);

        cm.CommandText = "With merged_1 as (Select p.Post_img, p.Poster_name, p.Caption, p.Post_id as id, COUNT(c.Post_id) as Com_number " +
                        "from Post p " +
                        "LEFT JOIN Comments c ON p.Post_id = c.Post_id " +
                        "Where p.Poster_name = \"Mo no\" group by p.Post_id), " +
                        "raw_post as (Select m.*, " +
                        "COUNT(l.Id) as Like_num, Post_liked(\"Gia Duc\", m.id)" +
                        " from merged_1 m " +
                        "LEFT JOIN Likes l ON m.id = l.id AND l._type = 0 group by m.id) " +
                        "Select f.BirthDay, f.User_name, f.Age, f.Avatar, f.Introduction, f.City, f.HomeTown, f.Follow_num" +
                        ", r.* from raw_post r INNER JOIN Fb_user f ON r.Poster_name = f.User_name;";

        cm.Parameters.Add("@_name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = user_name;
        cm.Parameters.Add("@_mine", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = MyUser;

        MySqlDataReader reader = cm.ExecuteReader();

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Load(reader);
        reader.Close();
```

Database connection is fine and It just works when I type in this exact command on MySQL workbench which returns 4 rows. However, the table.Rows.Count in the above code returns only one row.
The three table:

```sql
Create table Comments(
            Comment_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
            Post_id INT,
            Poster_name VARCHAR(30),
            Comment text,
            Comment_time DATETIME,
            Like_num INT
        );
    
       Create table Likes(
        User_name VARCHAR(30),
        _Type INT,
        Id INT);

      Create table Post(
    Post_img mediumblob,
    Poster_name Varchar(30),
    Caption text,
    Post_id INT
);

Create table Fb_user(
    BirthDay VARCHAR(30),
    User_name VARCHAR(30),
    Age INT,
    User_password VARCHAR(30),
    Avatar mediumBlob,
    Introduction text,
    City VARCHAR(30),
    HomeTown VARCHAR(30),
    Follow_num INT
);
```

"The exact same query" that I've mentioned:

```
With merged_1 as (Select p.Post_img, p.Poster_name, p.Caption, p.Post_id as id, COUNT(c.Post_id) as Com_number
                            from Post p
                            LEFT JOIN Comments c ON p.Post_id = c.Post_id
                            Where p.Poster_name = "Mo no" group by p.Post_id),
                            raw_post as (Select m.*,
                            COUNT(l.Id) as Like_num, Post_liked("Gia Duc", m.id)
                             from merged_1 m
                            LEFT JOIN Likes l ON m.id = l.id AND l._type = 0 group by m.id)
                            Select BirthDay, User_name, Age, Avatar, Introduction, City, HomeTown, Follow_num
                            , r.* from raw_post r INNER JOIN Fb_user f ON r.Poster_name = f.User_name;
```

I also did try the reverse. Copying the query that "works" in MYSQL back to C# code with no parameters added. Still the same result arises. I guess it's something wrong with the implementation of MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()...

Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: Can you add some sample data to this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9aef0f2d73d26fe5d1fc8718e8de8ea3), and the definitions of the table `Fb_user` ?

Comment: BTW: `inner join Fb_user f on true` will result in  a cross join, and might be the cause if `fb_user` does have 4 records.....

Comment: @Luuk Thanks for your comment. I've just updated the "exact same query" that I've mentioned...

Comment: @Luuk Changed the "On True" part. It's a mistype :(

Comment: The other difference is `p.Poster_name as _Name` vs. `p.Poster_name`

Comment: @Luuk That was for debugging. Not the cause, I guess. Changed it in my original code :(.

Comment: When the two queries are the same, and you still have a different output, then a sample of data is needed (in text format, or as dbfiddle) which makes your problem reproduceable (see [mre])

Comment: @Luuk https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4f8d1543f4b86d1c826129724dabf5ea

Comment: Sorry, I pass because of errors in te SQL (`this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`), and a  `Post_liked does not exist` in the DBFIDDLE

Comment: My column "f.User_name" is a primary key. Just drop primary key and everything works fine...

Comment: Is there something wrong with the subquery?

Comment: Nope. It seems like me assigning primary key to fb_user is the only thing wrong @Housheng-MSFT